# analysis of garbage collection logs using GCViewer

Tags: java, performance, memory, garbage-collection

I am trying to analyze my garbage collection logs using [GCviewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer/wiki). Since I am doing this for the first time so I am not sure how to read these metrics and what does each of these means? Below are the images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Can anyone explain me what does this metrics means? Is it bad? I mean it is taking lot of time in GC?

Comment: GCViewer just visualizes GC metrics. You need to learn about GCs and their properties first, it's not specific to GCViewer.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, the more time spent in GC means less time for the application.  There are different garbage collectors and different parameters for each that can change the behavior depending on what's more important - application responsiveness, memory usability, etc., - and there are complete books written on it.  But the simplest message is usually that you don't want to spend any more time in GC than absolutely necessary.